# Parent/Child association with custom entities. Why children entities "list" is empty on server side?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, associations, ria

Here is my problem:

I have an entity `DisplayMap` mapped to a database table. This entity is linked with a custom defined entity `MapBitmap`.

A `MapBitmap` can hava 0 to N `DisplayMap` and `DisplayMap` can have 0 or 1 `MapBitmap`. A `MapBitmap` is a custom entity (it's not a table of my database, in fact it represent a file on the server).

Here's the code :

```
[MetadataType(typeof(DisplayMapMetadata))]    
public partial class DisplayMap
{
    ...

    [DataMember]
    public int? MapBitmapId { get; set; }

    [Include]
    [DataMember]
    [Association("DisplayMap", "MapBitmapId", "Id", IsForeignKey = true)]
    public MapBitmap MapBitmap { get; set; }

    ..... 
  }

   [MetadataType(typeof(MapBitmapMetadata))]
   [DataContract]
   public partial class MapBitmap 
    {
    .....

    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    private List<DisplayMap> _DisplayMap = new List<DisplayMap>();
    [Include]
    [DataMember]
    [Association("DisplayMap", "Id", "MapBitmapId", IsForeignKey=false)]
    public List<DisplayMap> DisplayMap
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._DisplayMap == null)
            {
                this._DisplayMap = new List<DisplayMap>();
            }

            return this._DisplayMap;
        }
        set { this._DisplayMap = value; }
    }

   ...
   }
```

When I Insert from silverlight client a new `DisplayMap` and a new `MapBitmap`, on "Submit" everything works : on the server side, I can enumerate `DisplayMap` list of a `MapBitmap`, new `DisplayMap` child entities are present.

But, when I create a new `MapBitmap` and then link it to an existing `DisplayMap`, on the "Submit", on the server side, the list of `DisplayMap` of the new `MapBitmap` entity is empty. I don't understand why.

The strange things is that on the client side (silverlight), the relation is ok before the "SubmitChanges".

Does any one have an idea ? Thanks for any response.